# Very large differences using float and double

Tags: c++, precision

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int steps=1000000000;
    float s = 0;
    for (int i=1;i<(steps+1);i++){
       s +=  (i/2.0) ; 
    }
    cout << s << endl;
}
```

Declaring `s` as `float`: 9.0072e+15

Declaring `s` as `double`: 2.5e+17 (same result as implementing it in Julia)

I understand `double` has double precision than `float`, but `float` should still handle numbers up to 10^38.

I did read similar topics where results where not the same, but in that cases the differences were very small, here the difference is 25x.

I also add that using `long double` instead gives me the same result as `double`. If the matter is the precision, I would have expected to have something a bit different.

Comment: You are adding the error 1000000000 times. That is a huge number, so a large deviation is not too surprising.

Comment: float mantissa 24 bits means some whole numbers above `2^24 = 16777216` will have an error. So with `float` you are adding like 1.7% + some intermediates of your numbers without any error, rest is somewhere off the track. 64 bit floating point has whole number precision with 53 bit mantissa up to number 9007199254740992, which is more than your limit.

Comment: If you want precise sum of floating point numbers use other algorithms, such as Kahan summation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is the lack of precision: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point

After 100 million numbers you are adding 1e8 to 1e16 (or at least numbers of that magnitude), but single precision numbers are only accurate to 7 digits - so it is the same as adding 0 to 1e16; that's why your result is considerably lower for float.

Prefer double over float in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention what type of floating point numbers you are using, but I'm going to assume that you use IEEE 754, or similar.

> I understand double has double precision

To be more *precise* with the terminology, double uses twice as many bits. That's not double the number of reprensentable values, it's 4294967296 times as many representable values, despite being named "double precision".

> but float should still handle numbers up to 10^38.

Float can handle a few numbers up to that magnitude. But that does't mean that float values in that range are precise. For example, `3,4028235E+38` can be represented as a single precision float. How much would you imagine is the difference between the previous value representable by float? Is it the machine epsilon? Perhaps 0.1? Maybe 1? No. The difference is about 2E+31.

Now, your numbers aren't quite in that range. But, they're outside the continuous range of whole integers that can be precisely represented by float. The highest value in that range happens to be 16777217, or about 1.7E+7, which is way less than 2.5E+17. So, every addition beyond that range adds some error to the result. You perform a billion calculations so those errors add up.

---

Conclusions:

- Understand that single precision is way less precise than double precision.
- Avoid long sequences of calculations where precision errors can accumulate.

Answer (score 0):

Problem with floating point precision! Infinite real numbers cannot possibly be represented by the finite memory of a computer. Float, in general, are just approximations of the number they are meant to represent.

For more details, please check the following documentation:
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/101163/what-causes-floating-point-rounding-errors